# VIews Proximity Search Fields as Separate Block?

Tags: views, search, location

Just a quick question, or if someone can point me in the right direction...

I have a website that needs to have a search field where customers can enter a service (e.g. photography) in one field, and a post code/zip code in the other so search for services near them.

To do this, I have  a content type for each service with addressfield, geofield and geocoder modules installed, and I have a view set up with an exposed filter criteria to filter the results.

This all works perfectly.

What I would like to do is have the filter criteria search in an external block at the top of every page (like the default drupal search block) that will show a list of results on a NEW page whenever a customer submits the form. Using my current method, I first have to direct customers to the page with the view on before they can search.

I experimented with the Search Configuration module (https://drupal.org/project/search_config) which lets you use the existing drupal search block, but can limit the results to only show one content type, which is perfect, but doesnt include the location post code field, and doesnt have the configuration of displayed results like views fields would do.

If anyone could offer up a bit of advice of where to go next I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using drupal 7 You have an option to expose the filter as a block. and you can display the block in any region as you do all the other blocks. You would find this option under the advanced section in the views.

Please check the screenshot below

[image]